# How to design tables for players in a tournament?

Tags: mysql, database-design, physical-design

I need help with my database table design.

I have group which contains a list of players. In every group each player plays games with other players. Game has also some result for example 1:0 and there can be overtime too.

I already created some tables but I dont think this is a good solution. There is problem when I create java classes from these tables.

PlayerResult has lists of games. Game has opponent which is again PlayerResult which have listOfGame again etc... I dont know how to solve this cycle because every playerResult should know all their game to count score and point. Please help me improve the table design.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `GROUP` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `NAME` (`NAME`,`GROUP_ID`),
  KEY `TOURNAMENT_ID` (`TOURNAMENT_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PLAYER_RESULT` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `POINTS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RANK` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GROUP_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PLAYER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SCORE` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `PLAYER_ID` (`PLAYER_ID`),
  KEY `GROUP_ID` (`GROUP_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RESULT` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LEFT_SIDE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RIGHT_SIDE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OVERTIME` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `GAME` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PLAYER_RESULT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `OPPONENT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `RESULT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `VYSLEDKYHRACA_HRACA_ID` (`PLAYER_RESULT_ID`),
  KEY `RESULT_ID` (`RESULT_ID`),
  KEY `OPPONENT_ID` (`OPPONENT_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: I don't understand your system well enough to give a proper answer.  The DDL code you have included is helpful, but not quite enough for me.  Could you describe or further define the four entities your tables represent?  It seems like PLAYER_RESULT might represent the players, but that's not clear; nor is the difference between GAME and RESULT.

Comment: the system is common in sport sitation. One group where is players or teams which play matches (games) between us. In my case table game is has id opponent and player and Id result which I divided into left and right side and also overtime. Table game has just IDs to join player result and result

Comment: I'm still not quite clear on some of this but I will take a stab at what I think should work.  You can tell me if there is any functionality you need that my suggestion doesn't seem to address.

Comment: Any feedback?  Was it what you were looking for?

Comment: I need some time to think about ur example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED** version based on feedback:

```
CREATE TABLE group (
    group_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(team_id)
);

CREATE TABLE player (
    player_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    last_name VARCHAR(50),
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    group_id INT,
    player_rank INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(player_id)
);

CREATE TABLE game (
    game_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    match_date DATE,
    overtime TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (game_id)
);

CREATE TABLE player_game (
    game_id INT NOT NULL,
    player_id INT NOT NULL,
    player_score INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (game_id, player_id)
);
```

...and **UPDATED** explanation:
I think `group` and `player` are self-explanatory.  The table `game` will have one record per match.  The `player_game` table records the players in a match and the results; each match will have two records, one for each player.

Since you appear to be using InnoDB as the storage engine you may want to use foreign keys to enforce referential integrity, and obviously you can add other constraints and indexes as needed.  If you need some functionality that this doesn't seem to cover, ask and I will either explain or add it.